# Why does the Temple of the Sun God award no cash when it defeats balloons?

Tags: bloons-td-5

On an account my Temple of the Sun God rewards no money but it does reward exp. Why is that?

Comment: Im guessing because the temple of the sun god is a sort of ultimate tower. It is proved to be impassable in any difficulty campaign. You dont actually need a lot of money after you get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Temple of the Sun God is not a normal tower. It is a combo tower with a multitude of power and attack options. Because of this you will not receive the same amount of cash while you have one. This goes for both this tower and all of the special abilities you can unlock throughout the game.